# Jenkins sent cucumber html report that is not looking good

Tags: selenium, jenkins, webdriver, cucumber

The html file which i have received from jenkins is not looking as expected.

I have tried using Cucumber code below but it has not resolved my issue:

```
dref reportPath=build.getWorkspace().child("overview-failures.html")
msg.setContent(reportPath.readToString()."text/html")
**/cucumber-html-reports/overview-features.html
```

My expected result is that the html should look good.

[please find the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zEFr.png)

Comment: Please improve the formatting and show a screenshot that marks what you dislike

Comment: The attachment you posted is a broken link. Could you update your post with a working screenshot?

Comment: image added. Please check